# Get unique, permanant revision name in vc

Tags: git, version-control

I am writing some Elisp for a package. I was using `vc-working-revision` to identify the current revision. But it only returns the branch *name*, not the hash that name points to. Therefore, this information goes out of date quickly (`master` now is not `master` 20min from now).

(I was surprised. Branch names have little to do with revisions.)

I would like to (cross vc-system) get a unique identifier for the current head that is not time-sensitive with `vc`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

In case of Git you can call `vc-git--rev-parse` on return value of `vc-working-revision`. If you pass whatever what may or may not be SHA1, including branch names and "HEAD". It will also return valid SHA1's intact.

Unfortunately there isn't a guaranteed general solution that you're looking for. Interface we used is specific to Git and general API doesn't provide alternatives. This is knowledge that has to be introduced on per backend basis.

Comment: I feared this, but `(defadvice vc-git-working-revision
    (around use-hashes-only (file) activate)
    (setq ad-return-value (vc-git--rev-parse "HEAD")))` doesn't seem to work. I get different stale values from `vc-working-revision` (which differs from the results from `vc-git-working-revision`)